# Uncheck value for checkbox in jquery (with ajax and php)

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have an editable ajax table , and have a "unlock" field  with  a checkbox for every row.

When I check the chekbox I need to get the value 1 ( I'm ok for this part ! :)

My code to get the value of the cheked box:

(  `$("#unlock_input_" + ID).val();`   ) )

But when I uncheck one of any checkbox , I need to get the value 0 ( I need help for this part)

So.... How can I do that in jquery ?   Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this (using [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to ask for the checked-property):

```
var result = $("#unlock_input_" + ID).prop('checked')?1:0;
```

**EDIT:**
if you explicitly need the value instead of `1`, just do:

```
var element = $("#unlock_input_" + ID);
var result = element.prop('checked')?element.val():0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could throw on a `:checked` selector. Then you'll get back `undefined` when the box is unchecked, which is falsey, so:

```
var result = $("#unlock_input_" + ID + ":checked").val() || 0;
```

`result` will end up with the value of the checkbox if it's checked, or `0` if not, because of the way [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) works.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/isakog)

Another way to write it:

```
var result = $("#unlock_input_" + ID).filter(":checked").val() || 0;
```

Or of course, the rather more direct:

```
var cb = $("#unlock_input_" + ID)[0],
    result = cb.checked ? cb.value : 0;
```

Comment: @user1029834: My initial answer had an error in it, I've fixed it now (I left off the `:checked` selector).

Comment: Very much like the shortness of this ... I'd have probably gone down the `? :` route :)

Comment: @CD001: There are upsides and downsides. Using `:checked` is definitely going to perform worse than my last alternative above, but of course, unless you're in a tight loop, it doesn't matter. So it's horses for courses... :-) (What I do in *my* projects is use an extension method I add called `checkedVal`, which returns the value if checked using an efficient means or returns `undefined` if unchecked.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `checked` property of the checkbox to decide whether 1 or 0. Try this

```
if($("#unlock_input_" + ID)[0].checked){
    alert("1");
}
else{
    alert("0");
}
```

Alertnatively you can use jQuery `is` method to check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
if($("#unlock_input_" + ID).is(":checked")){
    alert("1");
}
else{
    alert("0");
}
```

Comment: `.is(":checked")` *shudder* ;-) If you're going to branch, I'd definitely branch your first way unless there's some possibility the checkbox won't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if it's chekced

```
if($("#unlock_input_" + ID).is(':checked')){
    myVal = "1";
}
else{
    myVal = "0";
}
```